# When an select option that is part of a dropdown list is deleted, how to make the field fall back to the default value in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, dropdown

I have a dropdown list called Reward. It is populated from the info submitted by users from a previous page.

This is how it looks [image]

Here is the code:

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
        this.state = {
            ...
            reward: this.props.bucket.reward || "",
            ...
        };

        ...
        this.onBucketRewardChanged = this.onBucketRewardChanged.bind(this);
        ...
    }

render() {
…
<div className="col-md-2">
   <label>
      <span className={''}>Reward<br/></span>
      <span className="text-danger">{this.getRewardErrorText()}</span>
   </label>
   <select className="form-control"
         value={this.state.reward}
         onChange={(e) => this.onBucketRewardChanged(bucketIdx, e)}>
      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please select a reward ...</option>
      {rewards.map(this.renderRewardIDs)}
   </select>
</div>
}

renderRewardIDs(reward, idx) {
   return (
      <option key={idx} value={reward.id}>{reward.id}</option>
   );
}

onBucketRewardChanged(bucketIdx, event) {
   this.setState({reward: event.target.value});
   …
}
```

The Reward dropdown list is an array of rewards that is built dynamically using a user input somewhere else, so the options in the rewards list will be changed (added or deleted) over time. The above code works with one exception. When a reward option is deleted, the entry where that reward option was previously selected doesn't behave that way I want it, the **display** of the reward fell automatically to the top item of the list, but when the form is saved, no value has been saved since it is not actually being selected.

I’d like the default value, “Please select a reward”, being displayed in the reward field when the previously chosen reward option was deleted, that will hopefully make users **explicitly** reselect one, but I cannot figure out how to make that happen. I'm still new to React, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying something like this:

```
value={rewards.find(obj=>(this.props.bucket.reward===obj.value))}
```

to replace

```
value={this.props.bucket.reward}
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Everything defaults back to "Please select a reward ..."